# How can I center a row within a jumbotron container despite its width and height, using bootstrap command?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where I am using a bootstrap jumbotron with a row. I am stuck with CSS and bootstrap to centre a row at the centre of the jumbotron container, making it responsive as a result. I am here because I have searched for the solution and did not find it.

```
`<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid img-fluid">
        <div class="row align-center jumbo-row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 align-self-center">
                <h1>BUILD UP YOUR BODY TODAY</h1>
                <h5>A truly epic gym</h5>
                <h5>OPEN 24/7</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Subscribe Now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS command:

```
.jumbotron {
background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
url("../images/photos/gym4.jpg");
color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 0;
-webkit-box-align: end;
-ms-flex-align: end;
align-items: flex-end;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
padding: 25px;}

.jumbotron h1 {
font-family: "Exo", font-family;
color: #ffff00;}

.jumbotron .container-fluid {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)}
```

[code outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSKyZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fortunately, I found the answer. I just had to add a container-fluid below the jumbotron tag and add two bootstrap commands, such as (align-items-center (vertical alignment)) and (justify-content-center (horizontal alignment)) within the row tag and it responcively aligned the col at the center of the jumbotron.

```
<div class=" jumbotron jumbotron-fluid ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 ">
                    <h1>BUILD UP YOUR BODY TODAY</h1>
                    <h5>A truly epic gym</h5>
                    <h5>OPEN 24/7</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Subscribe Now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```